# Sorting a pointer based on another pointer

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I don't know if I'm asking it right but what I mean is:

I have this code in plain C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return (*(int*)b - *(int*)a);
}

int main (int argc, char const *avrg[]) {
   int i;
   int *ani, *tira;

   srand(time(NULL));
   tira = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
   ani = malloc(10*sizeof(int));

   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      *(tira+i) = (rand()%10);
      *(ani+i) = i + 1;
   }

   qsort(tira, 10, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
   
   free(tira);
   free(ani);

   return 0;
}
```

As you can see I'm sorting "tira" with qsort() from greater to lesser and nothing for "ani".

What I want to do is to sort "ani" using the values of "tira", for example:

tira = (2,7,6,2,...)
ani = (1,2,3,4,...)

after sorting

tira = (7,6,2,2,...)
ani = (2,3,1,4,...)

I found some solutions with arrays but I'm not allowed to use them (it has to be pointers) and I couldn't translate those solutions for pointers.

Could anyone point 'wink wink' me in the right direction? ( Sorry for the bad joke XD )

Comment: If you want to keep the values together during the sort, put them in the same `struct` and reserve memory for that. Then you can sort them with member `tira` or with member `ani` if they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write your own sorting function to do this job.  `qsort()` is restricted to sorting objects that are contiguous in memory, and inasmuch as each of your logical objects is split across one element of `ani` and one of `tira`, they are discontiguous.

I'd just write an insertion sort or maybe a selection sort that takes both arrays as input.  It performs element comparisons based on the contents of `tira`, but whenever it performs a copy or swap, it applies both to an element of `tira` and to the corresponding element of `ani`.  The same approach can be applied to most other sorting routines, too, but insertion and selection sorts are particularly easy to write.

Comment: Thx! I did just what you said and it worked. This is what I came up with:

'
int swap (int *ani, int *tira, int l) {
   int i,j,temp1,temp2;

   for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
      for (j=i; j<l; j++) {
         if (*(tira+i) > *(tira+j)) {
            temp1=*(tira+i);
            *(tira+j)=*(tira+i);
            *(tira+i)=temp1;

            temp2=*(ani+i);
            *(ani+j)=*(ani+i);
            *(ani+i)=temp2;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
'

Answer (score 0):

You can't normally sort two different arrays.

But, if you create an auxiliary struct that remembers things about corresponding elements of `tira` and `ani` it is possible.

But, it can be a bit cumbersome and uses some extra memory. There are other ways to define the struct (e.g. index values, pointers, etc.)

Anyway, here is some code that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRMAX      10

struct idx {
    int tira;                           // tira value
    int ani;                            // ani value
};

void
print(const int *arr,const char *reason)
{
    int i;

    printf("%s:\n",reason);
    for (i = 0;  i < ARRMAX;  ++i)
        printf(" %d",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int
cmpfunc(const void *vpa, const void *vpb)
{
    const struct idx *ap = vpa;
    const struct idx *bp = vpb;

    return (bp->tira - ap->tira);
}

void
dotest(int randflg,int *tira,int *ani)
{
    int i;
    struct idx *idx;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ARRMAX; i++) {
        tira[i] = 0;
        ani[i] = 0;
    }

    do {
        if (! randflg) {
            tira[0] = 2;
            tira[1] = 7;
            tira[2] = 6;
            tira[3] = 2;

            ani[0] = 1;
            ani[1] = 2;
            ani[2] = 3;
            ani[3] = 4;
            break;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < ARRMAX; i++) {
            tira[i] = (rand() % 10);
            ani[i] = i + 1;
        }
    } while (0);

    print(tira,"tira unsorted");
    print(ani,"ani unsorted");

    struct idx *idxlist = malloc(ARRMAX * sizeof(struct idx));

    for (i = 0;  i < ARRMAX;  ++i) {
        idx = &idxlist[i];

        // get tira value
        idx->tira = tira[i];

        // get ani value
        idx->ani = ani[i];
    }

    qsort(idxlist, ARRMAX, sizeof(struct idx), cmpfunc);

    for (i = 0;  i < ARRMAX;  ++i) {
        idx = &idxlist[i];
        tira[i] = idx->tira;
        ani[i] = idx->ani;
    }

    print(tira,"tira sorted");
    print(ani,"ani sorted");

    free(idxlist);
}

int
main(int argc, char const *avrg[])
{
    int i;
    int *ani, *tira;

    srand(time(NULL));

    tira = malloc(ARRMAX * sizeof(int));
    ani = malloc(ARRMAX * sizeof(int));

    dotest(0,tira,ani);
    dotest(1,tira,ani);

    free(tira);
    free(ani);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
 tira unsorted:
 2 7 6 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
ani unsorted:
 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
tira sorted:
 7 6 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
ani sorted:
 2 3 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0

tira unsorted:
 7 1 1 5 4 3 4 8 6 4
ani unsorted:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
tira sorted:
 8 7 6 5 4 4 4 3 1 1
ani sorted:
 8 1 9 4 5 7 10 6 2 3
```

Comment: Thx for taking the time!! I've never would have sort a code like that!